# Are browser default font sizes dependent on DPI?

Tags: css, browser, font-size, dpi

I stumbled across http://informationarchitects.net/blog/100e2r/, a blog entry that argues for using browser 100% font sizes for body text. I was surprised that the text claimed that the font size on that page was the browser default size, as it is larger than I expected.

I took a look at the inherited style for body text from the above link, and it is the following:

```
font-size: 1.313em;
```

It is my understanding of style sheets that this means that fonts should render at 131.3% of the browser default size. So is the blog incorrect that the font size shown is the browser's default size?

The company's website has an Apple focus, so I thought maybe the answer to the question has to do with DPI settings since Apple defaults to 72 and Microsoft defaults to 96. 96/72 is close in value to 1.313.

I have my Chrome fonts set to the default size, 16. Since I'm running Windows, I think that means 16 pixels or 12 points. On a Mac, is the default font size also 16 pixels and therefore 16 points?

Comment: If you could isolate the question (e.g. "is 100% font size the same as 1em?") it would make it a lot easier to answer.

Comment: @valentinas My main confusion is because the website I identified says it shows text at the default size, but in my experience, it doesn't. Am I mistaken somehow? The extra details are to broaden the question to make it more useful for the community.

Comment: in that case the question falls under "too localised" category, because it's only relevant for that particular article from 2006.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 2006 when this article was written they had another design, found it in archive http://web.archive.org/web/20070706194102/http://www.informationarchitects.jp/100E2R/ — you can see `font: 100%/1.45 Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;` which gives 16px on default desktop browser :)

Comment: Good find! I guess that answers my question about the article being incorrect. Do you know if 16px is the standard default for Chrome on both Windows and OS X? I can confirm that 16 is the default, but I am not sure about the units.

Comment: As far as I know 16px is the default font size for all desktop browsers. Google Chrome on Windows and OSX use 16px as default too.